# Showing and hiding a selection when clicking on another selection on Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, select, selection

In a nutshell, only show the selection `#letters` when option `letters` is selected, selection `#numbers` comes out when option `numbers` is selected, `#letters` disappears and `#numbers` is enabled?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

This is visible at the beginning:

```
<select id="test">
    <option value="letters">letters</option>
    <option value="numbers">numbers</option>
</select>
```

After clicking `letters` shows or enable `#letters` and show `#numbers` when `numbers` is selected:

```
<select id="letters">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
</select>
<select id="numbers">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Post JS code that doesn't work so far.

Comment: Can you use jQuery ? or you want to do this using JavaScript only ?

Answer (score 0):

If I get it well, you want to create a dependent select box? If you select a first option, then you have more options coming.

I think this [tutorial](http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/select-box-change-dependent-options-dynamically) could help. It's made with jQuery. Pretty neat.

Comment: Dear @Yasser why did you removed my greeting message ? Is that forbiden to wish that I have been useful to someone followed by my name ?

Comment: Its not required. Check the faqs.

Comment: @Yasser, been [there](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) but didn't find anything. Can you point me your source?

Comment: my bad couldnt find in the faq too. But found it here - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use `jQuery` ([more information](http://jquery.com/)) and try the following code:

```
// bind all events AFTER the page is loaded
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test').change(function () {     // every time the user selects an option in your test <select>
        $('.yourSelect').hide();        // hide all <select>s with the class yourSelect
        $('#'+$(this).val()).show();    // show the <select> with the id selected in test
    });
});
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/myx7S/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is as simple as it gets - http://jsfiddle.net/yrshaikh/CBDaS/

```
function doSomething(){
    var selection = document.getElementById('test').value
    if(selection == "numbers") {        
        document.getElementById('letters').className = 'hide';
        document.getElementById('numbers').className = '';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('letters').className = '';
        document.getElementById('numbers').className = 'hide';
    }
}
```

and ofcourse, where .hide is a css class:

```
.hide {
    display:none;
}
```